# Android ContextMenu - не показывает

Tags: java, android, menu, context

При нажатии на кнопки в эмуляторе Genymotion, вместо того что открыть контекстное меню - нет никакой реакции. В логах ошибки нет. Проверил на стандартном эмуляторе, та же самая ошибка. В чем может быть проблема?

Main Activity :

```
package com.example.hasanshans.segundo;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button tvColor, tvSize;

final int MENU_COLOR_GREEN = 1;
final int MENU_COLOR_BLUE = 2;
final int MENU_COLOR_RED = 3;

final int MENU_SIZE_22 = 4;
final int MENU_SIZE_26 = 5;
final int MENU_SIZE_30 = 6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvColor);
    tvSize = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvSize);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    tvColor.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    registerForContextMenu(tvSize);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.tvColor:
            menu.add(0,MENU_COLOR_BLUE, 0, "BLUE");
            menu.add(0,MENU_COLOR_RED, 0, "RED");
            menu.add(0,MENU_COLOR_GREEN, 0, "GREEN");
            break;
        case R.id.tvSize:
            menu.add(0,MENU_SIZE_22, 0, "22");
            menu.add(0, MENU_SIZE_26, 0, "26");
            menu.add(0,MENU_SIZE_30, 0, "30");
            break;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_COLOR_RED:
            tvColor.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            tvColor.setText("Text color = red");
            break;
        case MENU_COLOR_GREEN:
            tvColor.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            tvColor.setText("Text color = green");
            break;
        case MENU_COLOR_BLUE:
            tvColor.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tvColor.setText("Text color = blue");
            break;
        // пункты меню для size
        case MENU_SIZE_22:
            tvSize.setTextSize(22);
            tvSize.setText("Text size = 22");
            break;
        case MENU_SIZE_26:
            tvSize.setTextSize(26);
            tvSize.setText("Text size = 26");
            break;
        case MENU_SIZE_30:
            tvSize.setTextSize(30);
            tvSize.setText("Text size = 30");
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/tvColor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/tvSize"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvColor"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: А на реальном девайсе работает? Может просто эмулятор не может в долгое нажатие...

Comment: оказывается надо было задержать кнопку на пару секунд :D

Comment: И нахождение ответа заняло меньше года! =) Думаю, стоит в ответ ваше решение написать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все сработало. Оказывается надо было задержать кнопку на пару секунд :D

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибаться, но попробуйте добавить при объявлении класса активити:

```
 implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener
```